# Can't instance a new Javascript object from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm having trouble making a new instance of a custom object from code behind.  I want to do this essentially on page load, once the DOM has been loaded, so I've been trying the following in my `Page.Load` event:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "loadShapes", "$(document).ready(function(){var loadedEvent = New CanvasState(document.getElementById('loadedEvent'));});", True)
```

`CanvasState()` is a custom function defined in my `<head>` tag.  The error I get is `Unexpected Identifier`, at the javascript generated by the above code.

Writing this up I get the sense that it could have to do with trying this in `Page.Load`.  Any other thoughts on it?

Comment: Have you used a master page? What is 'loadedEvent'?

Comment: Yes, using a master page.  `loadedEvent` is a canvas tag on this page. (the page is for requesting room layouts for events)

Comment: Is your canvas tag a runat="server" control?

Comment: No. Should it be? Are you thinking I'm not grabbing the proper ID for it?

Comment: No, It shouldn't. I was thinking this is a runat servet and you forgot use its client id. So I can not help, Sorry.

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying!

Comment: Thank you. But as a suggestion, You put your `CanvasState()` code here. Maybe some one could help. Your vb code is true and i think the problem is in CanvasState.

Comment: yes please,  More code